# Google Cloud platform 403-Insufficient permission

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm facing this issue when creating a storage bucket using Python. It clearly says I have insufficient permissions but I'm not getting where I went wrong.

I created an instance with the following settings: Default service account, Cloud API default access using the default scope.

This is the traceback of the error I am getting:

```
python2.7 sample.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 11, in <module>
    bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
  File "/home/naveen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py", line 264, in create_bucket
    bucket.create(client=self, project=project)
  File "/home/naveen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py", line 294, in create
    data=properties, _target_object=self)
  File "/home/naveen/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 293, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=banded-elevator-197103: Insufficient Permission
```

Comment: I would like to have more information about this issue. For example, you said you created an instance, but what kind of instance is it? Is it App Engine standard or flexible? If not the case, are you using Compute Engine. Please confirm so this question can be properly tagged and handled. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, it seems that you have not set the appropriate [access scopes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam) for the service account you are using.

You should update the service account you are using by adding the access scopes required for allowing you to create and update Cloud Storage buckets.

For example, if you want to add read and write access permissions to your service account, you can use this command.

```
gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes [YOUR_INSTANCE] \
--scopes=[LIST_OF_CURRENT_SCOPES, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write]
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me in solving the issue

Comment: If you think this answer was helpful for you, please consider accepting it. Thank you.